# Conversion from GUID to file?

Tags: guid

I have a somewhat rhetorical question. Is it possible to perform a rollback from a GUID to where in a directory structure files are located?

The background is that we are using an administrative tool for cases where documents on a daily basis get registered and added to the case and every time the document is given a unique GUID, so the next time you look for the particular document, the search will throw up a GUID link to that particular document.

Now comes the problem. Say that someone wants ALL documents in one particular case. The search will throw up one link for each document, sometimes more than 100, leaving you clicking links until insanity.

I would really like to know if it is possible to find out where in the directory structure ALL documents for a particular case are stored so I could perform a `cp * /my/choice/of/location`.

Could this be done?

Comment: You're assuming the GUID is generated off the source path in some way.  I wouldn't make that assumption; the spec for GUIDs allows for basically completely random GUIDs, which I'm guessing what's in use here.  In which case no, you can't go from random data back to some piece of information that was hanging around at the time the random thing was generated.

Comment: @Joe Surely there must be *some* way to do it. I don't read the question as assuming the GUID is generated from the source path. They must be stored somewhere and linked to the files they represent.

Comment: This question is unanswerable in its current form, as we have no idea what the "administrative tool" might be doing with the GUIDs it generates, or how the "particular case" might have documents associated with it. You should probably contact the authors/publishers of that unspecified "administrative tool" to get more information. GUIDs have no connection to the file system, so any information you're able to retrieve is going to be entirely dependent on the vendor's specific implementation details.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I am aware that the vendor of the system is the most appropriate to answer this question, but in such a dialogue it would be nice to know the fundamentals of the situation. My guess is that there is no connection (saved) between the source path and the GUID. But still, the files should physically hang around somewhere. The question is if they are in the same directory or spread out all over the partition?